# Tutorial for android application with PHONEGAP

Tags: android, cordova

I tried several question from this forum but could not get a "GOOD" tutorial for this
can anyone give me link to some good tutorial for getting started with phonegap

Can I get some android sample phonegap project to start learning phonegap

pls provide links here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this below two Tutorials

1. http://docs.phonegap.com
2. http://hiediutley.com/?s=PhoneGap%20Tutorial%20Series
3. [How to install/run PhoneGap on Ubuntu, Step by step guide](http://dasunhegoda.com/installrun-phonegap-ubuntu/797/)

Comment: plus there are plenty of books out there which will teach you the subject. Best way to learn it however is just experiment :D

Comment: @palani Kumar can I get some working project for android in phonegap where I can learn how things go in PHonegap

Comment: Try this http://coenraets.org/apps/directory/EmployeeDirectoryLocal.zip And You can find lot of Phonegap pulgins here =>github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Comment: another tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/